# MtGox Transaction IDs are internal or bitcoin issued?

Tags: transactions, mtgox

Why did MtGox issue me a transaction ID (and charge a fee) for funds that have not "transacted" to the address I provided (but have been withdrawn from MtGox)?

Do they issue some kind of internal transaction ID which does not lead anywhere when I search it in blockchain?